# Solution To Cat Litter

Tags: alternatives, pets

I have a cat that is fixed and fully de-clawed.  It is strictly an inside cat only and never goes outside.  I buy regular cat litter from the store frequently.  I would like to find an alternative.  I have tried newspaper and the cat didn't like it an neither did I.

The problem with the regular cat litter is that I don't know of anything I can do with it after it has been used.  I just throw it away in the normal garbage.  I am looking for something that I can use elsewhere after it is not longer used for cat litter.  Alternatively, I am looking for something that I already use around the house that I can use in place of the traditional cat litter.  Maybe something that has already filled its need and would otherwise be discarded.

So, is there a sustainable alternative to traditional cat litter?

Comment: Please be specific about what you hope to accomplish by changing litters, as "sustainable" is ambiguous.

Comment: I updated my question to be more specific

Comment: Declawing cats is a horrible practice. Declaw yourself!

Answer (score 11):

Most **cats are picky** about where they'll go poop. In my experience, if I just switch litters, they won't use the new one. Similarly, if I move the litter box, they may just go on the floor at the old location. So, whatever changes you are working on, go slowly.

Cats can be trained to use a **toilet**, which will use only drinking water, not litter, which may be an improvement. See YouTube.

One way to switch litters is to fill the litter box 2/3rds with the new litter, and then put a layer of the old litter on top. This will be familiar to the cat, while helping them become accustomed to the new litter.

There are **biodegradable cat litters** made from newspaper and sawdust. I like the sawdust ones a lot. Once your cat transitions to them, you can switch to **pellets** used for fuel, which are basically the same thing but cheaper.

If you use **Humanure**, you can then include the cat poop + pellets in your compost pile. Humanure incurs some additional responsibility, mostly making the compost pile big enough, and letting it sit long enough. See Joe Jenkins [*Humanure Handbook*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0964425831), also [available free online](http://humanurehandbook.com/downloads/Humanure_Handbook_all.pdf) for the full story.

Comment: @bstpierre: It lists several options. #5 is the link to read free online. I could link to that directly, but since Joe Jenkins sends people through that PDF, out of respect for him, I linked there, too.

Comment: this is what I get for not reading all the way to the end... thanks for pointing that out.